# Pentaho Kettle Connect to SAP

Tags: pentaho, kettle, sap-erp

Can anyone provide step by step instructions to connect kettle to SAP (ECC).

I need to know what steps I need to implement to create a connection and connect to either a table using `RFC_READ_TABLE` and to connect to a RFC

Comment: did you tried with the SAP Input step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wiki of Pentaho Kettle recommends JCO Connector:
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/SAP+Input

Download the connector and read the documentation. There are many guides available. Once you have a grasp understanding of the technology, discuss the integration with your SAP team - there are many other options that are more suitable for integration than RFC_READ_TABLE via JCo.